# Smallest ubuntu install : ubuntu-minimal, ubuntu-server..etc

Tags: grub2, apt

I am trying to trim down hard drive space requirements of ubuntu; for that reason, I am trying to get a bare minimum install of ubuntu

I tried (using a preseeding file) install the target as ubuntu-minimal, but it ran into 1.1GB (14.10)
I tried ubuntu-standard, which is around 917MB

All I want it is , grub2, kernel, ssh and a shell + login. Any dependency of these packages are all right. But how can I get this bare minimal install?

I tried ubuntu-core-remix. But, there is no installer and I have no idea to get the list of packages that distro has.

I am from redhat/fedora world. First time trying out ubuntu.

What do you suggest? go through apt-get, aptitude ..etc documentation? While I am at that, can someone suggest something that may take a little less time?

Thanks,

Comment: I got a very slim version by using server, and then just choosing what I wanted to install. You can install very minimal things, but you may have to mess with your mirror lists, and other settings.

Comment: I am going to try that out. But, how can I create a preseed file from an existing install? [http://askubuntu.com/questions/585970/replicate-an-ubuntu-installation-14-10]

Comment: I have not done this. This is a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html) to a how to (an old version 10.04) using a preconfig file and ubuntu installer, otherwise they do say you can use a [kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html) file.. but I think that is dated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is something that small. [Ubuntu Core](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) is probably the smallest of the [images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/) available, and still you get python and APT framework, and more stuff deemed essential. Here is an [installation example](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core/InstallationExample).

PS:There is no Ubuntu Core for 14.10.